# Pressing Action button twice crashes app

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My app is crashing in the iPad simulator when I press the action button again once it has already been pressed to open my activity view. I am concerned that this will be an issue if the user wants to press the button again to close the Popover rather than touching outside of it. Any suggestions are appreciated :)

FYI the Action button is a UIToolbar button.

In the .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *popup;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *activityViewProp;
```

In the .m:

```
-(IBAction)openUIActivityView:(id)sender {



    UIActivityViewController *activityView = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@"Hello World" applicationActivities:nil];


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        [self presentViewController:activityView animated:YES completion:^{    
        }];
    } else {

self.popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityView];

[self.popup presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES]; }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if you already have a popup, and do something else

```
-(IBAction)openUIActivityView:(id)sender {
    if (self.popup) {
        [self.popup dismiss ...];
    }
    else {
        // show popup code
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - I also needed to add self.popup = nil because otherwise it would not reopen  after it was closed. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, a view controller can only present one other view controller at any given time. Currently, when your tap the button a second time, you try to present a new instance of UIActivityViewController, while an other is already presented.

You can fix this, by checking the value of your main view controller's `presentedViewController` property. If it is not nil (and actually of type UIActivityViewController) you can return from the action without doing anything:

```
- (IBAction)openUIActivityView:(id)sender {
    if (!self.presentedViewController) {
        // We have no presented view controller yet.
        // <your current code here>
    } else {
        // We are already presenting a view controller.
        // Either dismiss it, or don't do anything.
}
```